# Which diagram shows the effect of catalysis on chemical equilibrium?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, kinetics, catalysis

My course book has the diagram in figure (1) to represent the effect of a catalyst on chemical equilibrium. I drew the second diagram in figure (2).

[image: effect of catalyst on chemical equilibrium]

When reviewing the diagram in figure (1), I observe the following mistakes:

1. The rate of catalyzed and uncatalyzed forward reaction  at equilibrium will be the same, which seems to be wrong because the value of rate constant of catalyzed forward reaction ($k_f$ catalyzed) more than the value of rate constant of uncatalyzed forward reaction ($k_f$ uncatalyzed), so the rate of catalyzed forward reaction at equilibrium = ($k_f$ catalyzed) $[A][B] > $ ($k_f$ uncatalyzed) $[A][B]$, so  it isn't the same as the diagram.
2. The rate of catalyzed forward reaction before equilibrium less than the rate of uncatalyzed forward reaction before equilibrium, which seems to be wrong too.

I need feed back about the diagram or both are wrong and about my reasoning.

Comment: OK, I'm bailing on the full answer. I'm 99% sure there is a mistake in the figure you were given and that the y axis should really be concentration, not rate (it was actually Mithoron who figured this out when I brought it up in chat after I found myself stumped). If this is the case, then figure 1 makes sense. To answer your questions in the comment above:  the rate of catalyzed forward rxn is always greater than the rate of the uncatalyzed forward rxn. Of course the same goes for the rates of the reverse rxns (catalyzed is faster). Sorry I can't answer your full Q more directly.

Comment: @airhuff thank you , 
1-  I  gave figure1   from course book and from internet, which i consider it wrong because it has the equilibrium at the same rate for the 4 reactions.

Comment: @airhuff 2- what about the answer of the second Q in the comment . Does the rate of catalyzed forward reaction before equilibrium will be less or more than the rate of uncatalyzed forward ?

Comment: The catalyzed forward reaction rate before equilibrium will be greater than that of the uncatalyzed forward reaction. This is how the catalyzed reaction reaches equilibrium faster than the uncatalyzed reaction.

Comment: Can you please include the source of the original figure?

Comment: @Martin-マーチンhttps://www.slideshare.net/Kumar4556/chemical-kinetics-55894275     slide Nu. 49 , refer  to  physical chemistry  book  by Atkins

Comment: @Martin-マーチンI think slide number 49 not completely right scientifically, because the diagram shows that rates of catalyzed and uncatalyzed froward reaction at equilibrium are equal which is untrue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (as suggested in the comments) the y-axis is supposed to represent concentration, such that the upper curve is "concentration of $\mathrm{A+B}$" and the lower curve is "concentration of $\mathrm{C+D}$", then Figure 1 is correct, albeit horribly mislabeled.

Your Figure 2 is correct if we want the y-axis to represent a rate-of-conversion instead, i.e., if the upper curve is "number of parcels of $\mathrm{A+B}$ being converted to $\mathrm{C+D}$ per second", and the lower curve is vice-versa. As you point out, a catalyst *increases* the conversion rate, and does so in both directions. So, exactly as you have drawn in Figure 2, those catalyzed rate curves should both be *higher* than their uncatalyzed siblings.

("Rate of reaction" is an awfully ambiguous term here – since at equilibrium, the rate of reaction must be zero!)

Comment: That can't be right. A catalyst does not change the location of the equilibrium. By definition, the rate of the forward reaction has to equal the rate of the reverse reaction.

Comment: Yes, but the catalyst here (in my reading of Figure 2) isn't changing the position of the equilibrium, right? The catalyst increases the rate-of-conversion-of-A-to-C, and also increases the rate-of-conversion-of-C-to-A. Our uncatalyzed rates at equilibrium might be one-parcel-per-second, then with the catalyst they might be two-parcels-per-second.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was mixing rates with concentrations. This is confusing.

Comment: I think your second assumption is the one we need.

Comment: @Jan you mean Figure 2 is correct

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect. At equilibrium, the rate of the forward reaction equals the rate of the reverse reaction, so there is not change in the amount of reactants or products. The apparent rate is zero, but the reactions still happen.

Comment: @LDC3 The IUPAC definition of "rate of reaction" has the form d[A]/dt, which at equilibrium must be zero. "Rate of forward reaction" and "rate of reverse reaction" are properly called "chemical flux", though of course everyone uses and understands the "rate of _____ reaction" notation.

Answer (score 1):

To know the exact diagram represent the effect of catalysis on chemical equilibrium, I searched on experimental data but I can't find suitable data.
 so I consider a hypothetical reversible first -order reaction in each direction where 
$$\ce{ A <=> B}$$
I choose those two equations for reversible first- order reaction to calculate the concentrations of product and reactant at a different time:
$$\ce{[A]}=\frac{k_b +K_fe^{-(k_f+k_b)t} }{k_f+k_b}{[A]_0}$$

$$\ce{[B]}=\frac{k_f -K_fe^{-(k_f+k_b)t} }{k_f+k_b}{[A]_0}$$

Starting with A at a concentration$[A]_0={0.6}$ and the values of the rate constants of uncatalayzed reaction are $k_f=3s^{-1}$ and $k_b=1s^{-1}$.
and the values of the rate constants of catalayzed reaction are $k_f=6s^{-1}$ and $k_b=2s^{-1}$

I did the calculation using excel sheet and draw the graph of concentration Vs time :
[image]

Depending on the rate  law expression$(r_f=k_f [A])\ and\ (\ r_b =k_b [B])$ I did the calculation using excel sheet and draw the graph of rate Vs time

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Figure 1 shows the rate as $k_f [A][B]$ whereas Figure 2 shows only $k_f$. This is why Figure 1 has the equilibrium at the same rate for the 4 reactions.

Comment: Figure 1 has the equilibrium at the same rate for the 4 reactions,   and Figure 2 show the rate at equilibrium more when catalyzed.so :Which Figure shows the effect of catalysis on chemical equilibrium?

Comment: Can you please explain how" Figure 2 shows only $k_f$"

Comment: @AdnanAL-Amleh $k_f$ is how fast the reaction occurs. Therefore, the rate of reaction with a catalyst will always be faster than without a catalyst (curves 4 and 5 must be greater than curves 1 and 2 at all times). When you multiply $k_f$ with $[A][B]$ and call that the rate, then the figure looks like Figure 1.

Comment: As you said curve 4  must be greater than curve 1  at all times,can I conclude Fig1 is not correct , because it shows curve 4 less than curve 1.

Comment: @AdnanAL-Amleh Figure 1 is correct if you take the product $k_f [A][B]$, not just $k_f$ alone.

Comment: I take into my consideration the $r_f$ as $k_f  [A][B]$ in figure1 , which means the 2  forward  reactions(catalayzed and uncatalayzed) haven't   the same rate at equilibrium  ,   but figure1 show  the same rate for  all the 4 reactions at equilibrium , so can I conclude figure1 isn't  correct?